# Trying to understand Child combinator in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to style just the first level of `li`, it looks like a child combinator should work, but as the demo below shows every `li` is red. I would expect only the first level (not nested) `li` to be styled red.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
.list > li {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>1st level</li>
  <li>1st level</li>
  <li>1st level
      <ul>
          <li>2nd level</li>
          <li>2nd level</li>
          <li>2nd level</li>
          <li>2nd level</li>
          <li>2nd level</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li>1st level</li>
  <li>1st level</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The "nested" `<li>`s *are* first-level children of the (nested) `<ul>`.

Comment: Yes, I thought using the child descendent > would stop the styles cascading down to the nested li (ul li ul li).

Comment: Take a look at this https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/#article-header-id-0

Edit: Just spotted the nested list in the CSS Tricks example isn't a `ul` it's a `ol`

Answer (score 5):

The `ul` selector matches the `<ul>` on line 1 of your code **and** the `<ul>` on line 5 of your code.

[image: Diagram of child relationships]

You'd need something more specific to make `ul` match only the one on line 1 (e.g. `:not(li) > ul > li`) … but even then, the default value of the `color` property is `inherit` not `black`, so the colour would still be copied from the parent element even though the selector wouldn't cause the rule to match it.

So you'd need to explicitly set the color of the nested element:

```
ul > li { color: red; }
ul > li li { color: black; }
```

Comment: If `>` doesn't stop the style cascade, what's the difference between `ul > li` and `ul li`?

Comment: @StephenMeehan — The former won't match a `<li>` in an `<ol>` in a `<li>` in a `<ul>`

Answer (score 1):

Your selector will style *"Any `<li>` element that is a direct child of a `<ul>` element"*, which stands true for *all* of your `<li>` elements.

You could override all inner `<ul>` elements by doing `ul ul > li` and setting them back to black instead.

```css
ul > li { color: red; }
ul ul > li { color: black; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1st level</li>
  <li>1st level</li>
  <li>1st level
      <ul>
          <li>2nd level</li>
          <li>2nd level</li>
          <li>2nd level</li>
          <li>2nd level</li>
          <li>2nd level</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li>1st level</li>
  <li>1st level</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -3):

```css
#outer-list > li {
  color: red;
}
#inner-list > li {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul id="outer-list">
  <li>1st level</li>
  <li>1st level</li>
  <li>1st level
      <ul id="inner-list">
          <li>2nd level</li>
          <li>2nd level</li>
          <li>2nd level</li>
          <li>2nd level</li>
          <li>2nd level</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li>1st level</li>
  <li>1st level</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Sushma, but I'm trying to achieve this with just CSS. I'm not able to add IDs or classes to the markup. I know it can be done with CSS. :)